# Inserting Hyperlinks in VBA Userform Lookup

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, userform

I have created a userform which included a number of items. In another worksheet I have a list of those items with specific urls. I am wanting the Userform to insert the hyperlink for me. I have come up with the below code which works when not part of an irow.

I did a test with the below code and worked perfectly.

```
Sub Hyperlinkstest()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = ws.Range("B2")

rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:=Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws.Range("A2"), ws2.Range("A:B"), 2, False), TextToDisplay:="Info"

End Sub
```

However when I have attempted to integrate it into my userform I am finding little success. Can someone please assist? The issue I am getting is in writing the code. It is saying that my row with ws.cells(iRow, 4).Value = ... has an expected end of statement. I am sure I am just overlooking something here and in need of a fresh set of eyes.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Database")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("LookupVals")
Set rng = ws.Cells(iRow, 4)

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    If RmRef.Value = "" Then
        RmRef.SetFocus
            MsgBox "Please Enter Room Reference"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = RmRef.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = RetMod.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:=WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RetMod.value, ws2.Range("A:B"), 2, False), TextToDisplay:="Info"
    ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = OdCd.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = hmm.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = lmm.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = rdtyp.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = dtt.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Wts.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Qt.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 12).Value = LP.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 13).Value = Dc.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 14).Value = TP.Value

    'clear the data
    RmRf.Value = ""
    Rdd.Value = ""
    OdCd.Value = ""
    hmm.Value = ""
    lmm.Value = ""
    rdtyp.Value = ""
    dtt.Value = ""
    Wts.Value = ""
    Qt.Value = ""
    LP.Value = ""
    Dt.Value = ""
    TTpr.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to enclose everything after `rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add` into brackets `()` like `rng.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=rng, …)`. Parameters submitted to a function need to be in brackets unless you don't expect a value to be returned. *Note: I close-voted for this question because of typographical error only.*

Comment: @Peh thanks for that. It worked a treat. I am curious why would it need brackets in this however in my test that worked I did not need this?

Comment: In your test you don't expect a result from the `.add()` function you just call the function -> no brackets. But in your `command_click` you expect a result from `.add()` which is saved in `ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value` then -> brackets needed.